# I want to merge data in a single column according to the unique bill no in R

Tags: r

The data is like this

```
1.  CM-00063262-15  EARRINGS
2.  CM-00063262-15  EARRINGS
3.  CM-00063262-15  NECKLACE
4.  CM-00063262-15  WALLET-WOMEN'S
5.  CM-00063263-15  SLACKS
6.  CM-00063264-15  BATH TUB
7.  CM-00063264-15  GIFT SET
```

I want output like this

```
1.  CM-00063262-15  EARRINGS,EARRINGS,NECKLACE,WALLET-WOMEN'S
2.  CM-00063263-15  SLACKS
3.  CM-00063264-15  BATH TUB,GIFT SET
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please read [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how do I ask a good question, [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) How to create a MCVE as well as [(3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610) how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

We need to extract the bill number and use it as grouping variable,

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,  toString(unique(sub("\\S+", "", Col))), 
                        by = .(grp = sub("\\s+.*", "", Col))]
#             grp                                    V1
#1: CM-00063262-15  EARRINGS,  NECKLACE,  WALLET-WOMEN'S
#2: CM-00063263-15                                SLACKS
#3: CM-00063264-15                   BATH TUB,  GIFT SET
```

If the OP's dataset have two columns instead of one, it is much easier

```
setDT(df1)[, toString(unique(Col2)), by = Col1]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col = c("CM-00063262-15 EARRINGS", 
 "CM-00063262-15 EARRINGS", 
"CM-00063262-15 NECKLACE", "CM-00063262-15 WALLET-WOMEN'S", "CM-00063263-15 SLACKS", 
"CM-00063264-15 BATH TUB", "CM-00063264-15 GIFT SET")),
 .Names = "Col", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
aggregate(data=df,V2~V1,FUN=paste)
```